# Push multiple values into an array in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push multiple values into an array based on the elements ID.

I expect the outcome to be `3` and `4` but instead I get `1 2 3 4`. Why is that the case in the following example?

```js
var myArray = [];
$( '#bla' ).each( function() {
   myArray.push( {
     test: $( this ).text(),
   });
});
console.log( myArray );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div id="bla">3</div>
    <div id="bla">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not related to you question: IDs should be **unique**. Use classes instead.

Comment: Repeating an id is never a good idea (should be a unique identifier)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - why is that not related?

Comment: Well this is using `jQuery` which you haven't tagged in your question so be sure to check you have included the `jQuery` library and you shouldn't duplicate **ID**'s. **ID**'s are supposed to be unique. I would recommend you swap from using `id`'s to using a `class` name. While testing things in `javascript` **/** `jQuery` I would also recommend you open the browser console so you can see any errors that might be reported/given. This will also tell you the cause of error and which line this error has occurred on.

Comment: No way you are getting `1 2 3 4` from that code

Comment: @Amit I didn't even read the whole code before commenting, I simply saw those repeated IDs. But they are, in fact, related to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the content of the your HTML, and not the `console.log`.

This is what you need to fix:

1. Include jQuery
2. Use class instead of id - there can be only one id in a document, so you'll get only one result
3. Look at the console

```js
var myArray = [];
$( '.bla' ).each( function() {
   myArray.push( {
     test: $( this ).text(),
   });
});
console.log( myArray );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="bla">3</div>
    <div class="bla">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First id has to be unique
replace id with class and use your snippet

```js
var myArray = [];
$( '.bla' ).each( function() {
   myArray.push( {
     test: $( this ).text(),
   });
});
console.log( myArray );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="bla">3</div>
    <div class="bla">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have two HTML elements with same id attribute. It is unique indeficator, it should be only one on page.

And second, if you are using your js script from external (not inluded between `<scritp></script>`) you should use (`document.ready` or in jQuery `$(docuemnt).ready(function(){})` [in my case it is short way to do this]), because you don't want to read HTML values before your is not loaded.

```js
(function () {
  var myArray = [];

  $( '.bla' ).each( function() {
    myArray.push( {
      test: $( this ).text(),
    });
  });
  
  console.log( myArray );
}());
```

```html
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="bla">3</div>
    <div class="bla">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're doing nothing other than replacing `id` with `class`